# Page width is too wide - Magento Go

Tags: magento-1.7, theme

A few weeks ago, my Magento Go website begin acting strange as far as the width of the website. When you load it, the website is completely centered but you have the ability to scroll right pretty far. I think it also depends on the size of your monitor.

Website: http://collegiatestorageandrental.gostorego.com/

This is what it looks like when it is loaded:

[image: Centered]

This is what it looks like when I scroll all the way to the right

[image: This is as far as I could scroll to the right]

How can I get it to not be able to scroll to the right?

Comment: Hi Dustin and welcome to magento.stackexchange.com! I'm sure your problem is css related and no magento problem, so I'm sorry but your question will be closed. Please ask your question again on stackoverflow.com. I'm not good in frontend, but I think your problem is here: media="all"
@media (min-width: 1200px)
.container, .wrapper {
width: 1000px;
}

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a CSS problem

Comment: No problem, great you are here. Here is an explanation what this is about: https://magento.stackexchange.com/tour on the upper right, you find a link to meta.magento.stackexchange.com if you want to have a look about what this side is _EXACTLY_ about :o)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The CSS for your `.footer-bottom` div is the issue.

Make the following changes (refer to [Magento Go CSS editing instructions if necessary](http://go.magento.com/support/kb/entry/name/customizing-the-look-and-feel-of-your-theme-using-the-css-editor/)):

- Change `clear: right` to `clear: both`
- Change `width: 990px` to `width: auto`
- Remove `margin-right: -990px`

[image: Screenshot of effects of corrected CSS]

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm fairly new to CSS so I made those adjustments to move the three images on the bottom to be flush with the newsletter signup. Is there a better way to do that than what I did?

Comment: *"Is there a better way to do that than what I did?"* - depends on content needs for that area across the site & across time. For now this will solve your problem.

Comment: I meant is there a better way to move the images flush with the newsletter signup without extending the width of the page?

Comment: Simplest way now is to remove the `left` positioning and set the `width: 920px`. Ideally though you should have the footer elements content & styling such that you can float the div to the right and it will line up based on its container.